# Programatically associating file types with .jar file

Tags: java

I know how to manually associate a file type with a .jar file:

```
assoc .ext=filetype
ftype filetype="C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "path\to\jar\file\YourJarFile.jar" "%1"
```

I'm currently using Runtime.exec() to try to do these commands, but I'm getting `Access is denied.` from the assoc command. I assume I need administrator privileges to run assoc, how can one do this from a java application?

Comment: Does your app. have a GUI?  Can you distribute it from a web site?

Comment: It doesn't have a GUI, I was just throwing together a quick test to see if I could do this from java.

Comment: I'd recommend you do this from an installer or native code or batch file that runs elevated. See my comments below under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try cmd /c assoc or such. It's an embedded command processor command

Comment: I decided to switch from ProcessBuilder to Runtime.exec() and cmd /c fixed my problems. Now I'm getting access denied errors from the assoc command.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised that that's a privileged command. You then have 2 choices: Run java elevated (bad idea security wise), or call a service or other process that is running all the time in native code. Or give up (that's a 3rd choice).

Comment: I decided to go the .bat file method. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

That should have connections with environnements context. try using the complete file path to assoc

Comment: What is the complete file path? I couldn't find it in the system32 folder.

Comment: MJB said that assoc is an embedded command, that appears to be the case.